# moving/animated vote counter widget - can the animation be user configured - off

Tags: feature-request

All,

In the past day or two, the little vote widget for questions has started following the question up and down the window for the extent of the question. If it is a long question, that little widget becomes quite annoying.

While I'm all for improvement, I caution against adding all the latest 'gee-whiz' animated bells and whistles just because you can. SO is clean and non-intrusive. The more animated widgets get added, the closer the site moves to the dividing line between **clean/enjoyable** and **annoying**. The line is different for all users, and I'll admit that I prefer a clean usable interface without animated distractions.

This isn't a complaint saying remove it, but rather a suggestion that animated parts of the site have some type of user-preference that allows users who find the moving widgets annoying to simply -- turn them off. (or disable moving animations, or something similar)

The script features that update your comment inbox, etc. are all perfectly fine, they provide no distraction because they don't move. Having the vote counter flittering up/down the left side of the browser window is something I would like to turn off. Recognizing others may love it and think it is the greatest thing since sliced-bread, don't de-animate it, but please find a way to allow users to turn it off.

Remember, somebody's latest gee-whiz feature, is a bug to someone else -- if it can't be turned off.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35041/175248 < describes the feature.  May be better to take it to Meta.SE and discuss it there. Your seeing it means you're part of the split test.

Comment: @Makoto So you're saying that not everyone has the "chance" to see it?

Comment: Right.  If you don't see it you're not in the split test.

Comment: I'm okay with it (a friend of mine at work showed it to me) but it would be nice to have it be configurable so if we don't want to see it we don't have to :).